# How to make a custom route of .NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Ok, when we first run a web api project, we normally have this in WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then what if I want to make a new route other than using {controller} so it's gonna be something like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/queries/{query}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And I have my custom class to retrieve a name list like this:

```
public class GetNameListQuery
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<String> GetNames(){ 
              return new String[] { "John" , "Adams" };
        }
    }
```

So that when I run the URI "mylocalhost/api/queries/GetNameList" I get the names "John" and "Adams". I'm a newbie in .NET and not sure there are any ways to do something like this. Appreciate your help. Thank you !!

Comment: In 4.5 or 4.6+ MVC allows the `[HttpGet]` to have a URL for the route. See :Attribute routing with Http[Verb] attributes in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and also the paragraph above - does that work for you? Read that entire article :)

Answer (score 0):

in your route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "DefaultApi2",
      "api/queries/{action}",
      new { controller = "Query" }
);
```

then create controller Query

```
public class QueryController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<String> GetNames()
    {
        return new String[] { "John", "Adams" };
    }
}
```

access this route : http://localhost/api/query/GetNameList